# regex for exactly n possible values which are unique

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions, formal-grammar

I want to write a regular expression in my python code, but I think this is more of a mathematical challenge.

So my requirement is, suppose I want to create $3$ unique coupon codes, I can write a regular expression like `[a-z]{3}` this would allow me to match any three character coupon code, but there are more than $3$ possible result space for the given regex, it is $26^{3}$ possible values here.

I was thinking of creating a regex which would have a dynamic base like say binary, or hexadecimal or decimal with a varying length of allowed characters, this would allow me to create at most $x$ number of coupon codes where $x > n$.

And then have another regex with a result space of $y$, that would negate into the extra result space of $x$, such that $n = x - y$

Is this possible? What are your opinions?

Comment: I mean, `^(abc|123|456)$` seems to work. Maybe I'm not understanding the question?